# Copying global array into an array referenced by a double pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a function within a file that takes in a pointer to an array represented by a double pointer. I want to copy the contents of a global array within the file to it. But when I dump the array, the data is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I have malloc'd enough memory for the double pointer to array and pass it into the function using its address

```
File1:

struct Data DataArray[10];    //global structure

CopyGlobalArray (void ***ArrayBuffer)
{
    memcpy(*ArrayBuffer, &DataArray[0], sizeof(DataArray);
}


File2:

function() {
   Data **MyArray = malloc(sizeof(Data) * 10);
   CopyGlobalArray(&MyArray);

   for (index =0; index<10 ; index++){
     printf(MyArray[Index]->FirstName);
     printf(MyArray[Index]->LastName);
   }
}
```

Comment: `ArrayBuffer` looks like triple pointer, not double. also `)` is missing for the `memcpy` call. Please post your *real* code.

Comment: Ah, `ArrayBuffer` is a double pointer to `void*`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the actual problem you try to solve? To really be able to help you we need to see a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (and know that you tried to debug it yourself, SO is not a free debugging service). And that `memcpy` call with the parameters you pass? That just seems wrong to me, `*ArrayBuffer` is not an array (or a pointer to the first element of an array) of `Data` elements.

Comment: Why the heck do you want to do that??? Just pass `void *` and `memcopy`.

Comment: You allocate memory for `10 * sizeof(struct Data)` bytes. The `malloc` function returns a *pointer* to the first byte. ***A*** pointer, not a pointer to a pointer. And using the address-of operator to pass a pointer to `MyArray` makes no sense.

Comment: The code I write is not standard C. But just trying to understand conceptually if I were to use a double pointer to represent an array, rather than the explicit array

Answer (score 1):

It might be hard to visualize, so lets draw the relationship:

The `malloc` function returns a pointer:

```
+-------------------+     +----------------------+
| pointer to memory | --> | The actual memory... |
+-------------------+     +----------------------+
```

However, you declare `MyArray` as a pointer to a pointer (do `struct Data`), which is more like

```
+---------+     +-------------------+     +----------------------+
| MyArray | --> | pointer to memory | --> | The actual memory... |
+---------+     +-------------------+     +----------------------+
```

The problem is that `MyArray` doesn't really point to a pointer, it points directly to the actual memory, which means the code will not be correct.

Comment: This makes a little more sense thank you. Will make some modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing double pointer to void*.You can just do this by a single void*.
You can do like this:

```
 File1:

struct Data DataArray[10];    //global structure

CopyGlobalArray (void *ArrayBuffer)
{
     memcpy(ArrayBuffer, DataArray, sizeof(DataArray);
}


File2:

function() {
    Data *MyArray = malloc(sizeof(Data) * 10);
    CopyGlobalArray(MyArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the copy function isn't charged with alocating the memory for the copy, a single pointer is sufficient:

```
struct Data DataArray[10];    //global structure

CopyGlobalArray (void *ArrayBuffer)
{
     memcpy(ArrayBuffer, DataArray, sizeof(DataArray));
}
```

If the function is charged with allocating the memory for the copy, you need a double pointer or use the return value, the latter being prefered:

```
struct Data DataArray[10];    //global structure

void *CopyGlobalArray (void)
{
     void *copy;
     if (copy=malloc(sizeof(DataArray)))
         memcpy(copy, DataArray, sizeof(DataArray));
     return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you declare `MyArray` as a doble pointer

```
  Data **MyArray = malloc(sizeof(Data) * 10);
```

the result of `malloc` should be casted to the double pointer:

```
 struct Data **MyArray = (struct Data**) malloc(sizeof(Data) * 10);
```

But providing a single pointer to the array of `struct Data` should be sufficient for your needs:

```
void CopyGlobalArray (void *ArrayBuffer)
{
     memcpy(ArrayBuffer, DataArray, sizeof(DataArray));
}
```

This is how could you use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Data
{
    char * FirstName;
    char * LastName;
};

// global structure
struct Data DataArray[] = {  {.FirstName = "Fred",  .LastName= "Smith"}, {.FirstName = "Eva",  .LastName= "White"}, {.FirstName = "John",  .LastName= "Rock"} }; 

void CopyGlobalArray (void *ArrayBuffer)
{
     memcpy(ArrayBuffer, DataArray, sizeof(DataArray));
}

void print(struct Data *array )
{
    for(size_t i=0; i < sizeof(DataArray)/sizeof(DataArray[0]); i++)
    {
      printf("%s",  array[i].FirstName);
      printf("%s\n", array[i].LastName);
    }
}

struct Data *function()
{
   struct Data *MyArray = (struct Data *) (malloc (sizeof(DataArray) ) );

    CopyGlobalArray (MyArray);

    // Copied array
    printf("\nMyArray:\n");
    print(MyArray);

   return MyArray; 
}

int main(void)
{
     // Original 
    printf("\nDataArray:\n");
    print(DataArray);

    struct Data *MyArray1 = function();

    printf("\nMyArray1:\n");
    print(MyArray1);   

    free(MyArray1); // free the array allocated inside function()
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
DataArray:
FredSmith
EvaWhite
JohnRock

MyArray:
FredSmith
EvaWhite
JohnRock

MyArray1:
FredSmith
EvaWhite
JohnRock
```